# Get specific values from PHP Array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'd like to get some values out of an array and print them out on the page.

For [1], these things should be extracted: `USD 7.0269 6.4119 0.14231 0.15596`

The array looks like this:

```
print_r($arr);
[1] => USD United States of America 7.0269  6.4119  Dollars 0.14231 0.15596  � Copyright 2003-2011. Powered by CurrencyXchanger 3.580 
[2] => EUR  Euro Member Countries 9.0373    8.3253  Euro    0.1107  0.1201   � Copyright 2003-2011. Powered by CurrencyXchanger 3.580
```

What is the best solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `preg_match_all()` after I trim off the area of interest:

```
foreach ($arr as $line) {
    // currency is in the first four characters (apparently)
    $currency = substr($line, 0, 4);

    // we use everything left of 'Copyright'
    $rest = strstr($line, 'Copyright', true);

    // match each occurrence of nn.nnnn
    if (preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+/', $rest, $matches)) {
        // $matches[0] contains all the amounts
        echo $currency, ' ', join(' ', $matches[0]), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

For PHP < 5.2 you need this line to calculate `$rest`:

```
$rest = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, 'Copyright'));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2tTmDd)

Comment: No need for the capturing group. Otherwise, +1!

Comment: Looks good. I get this error though "Wrong parameter count for strstr()"

Comment: Works like a charm! I had to change to $currency = substr($line, 0, 4); as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex solution:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $item)
{
    preg_match('/^([A-Z]){3}[\sA-Za-z]+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)/', $item, $matches);
    $result[$key] = array_shift($matches);
}
```

The regex corresponds to your pattern and captures everything you want inside consecutive elements of `$matches`. Since `$matches[0]` represents the full match, we remove the first element and assign it to your result array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 foreach($arr as $v) {
  $items = explode(' ', $v);
  $new_arr[] = $items[0]; //Getting the currency type
  foreach($items as $k => $m) {
    if(is_numeric($m) && floor($m) != $m && $k != (count($items) - 1))
      $new_arr[] = $m;
  }
 }

 //displaying the $new_arr
 foreach($new_arr as $n) {      
  if(is_numeric($n) === FALSE)
    echo "\n";     
    echo $n . ' ';
 }
```

See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/QSXNRwzu)

Comment: That would also get the last numbers. (Although, I don't know whether that is an actual issue)

Comment: Edited my answer, to not get the last numbers.

Answer (score 0):

With Regular Expressions you can get it.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    preg_match_all('/(\d+\.\d+)/', $value, $matches);
    $result[substr($value, 0, 3)] = array_shift($matches);
}
```

You get an Array like this

```
var_dump($result);
array (
    'USD' => array( 7.0269, 6.4119, 0.14231,  0.15596 )
    'EUR' => array( 9.0373, 8.3253, 0.1107,  0.1201 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Done quickly:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($string) {
        preg_match_all('/(\d+\.\d+)\s/', $string, $matches);
        return substr($string, 0, 3) . ' ' . implode(' ', $matches[1]);
    },
    $arr
);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => USD 7.0269 6.4119 0.14231 0.15596
    [1] => EUR 9.0373 8.3253 0.1107 0.1201
)
```